# Android Gridview not showing view at position 0 well

Tags: android, android-layout, gridview, android-gridview

I'm new to android development and I'm facing a small difficulty regarding the `GridView`. I have a `Gridview` in my first class called Game and I added a `BaseAdapter` called `GameAdapter`. The code is working fine but when adding the views to the `GridView`, it doesn't show the first element (at position 0).

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {

    Button b;
    if (convertView == null) {
        b = new Button(mContext);
        b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth() / (Game.cols), parent.getHeight() / (Game.rows + 1)));
        //b.setHeight(Game.gv.getMeasuredHeight() / Game.rows);
    } else {
        b = (Button) convertView;
    }
    Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(Game.splittedBitmaps[position]);
    b.setBackground(d);
    b.setId(position);
    b.setTag("Image_" + position);
    b.setOnClickListener(Game.s);
    Game.buttons[position] = b;
    return b;
}
```

Assume: `mContext` is the Context of the Game class, cols and raw are static integers in the Game class representing number go columns and rows respectively, `gv` is the actual `GridView` in Game, `Game.splittedBitmaps[]` is an array containing the Bitmaps to be set as backgrounds.

So this is my `getView()` code. Note that when I have the line code:

```
b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth() / (Game.cols), parent.getHeight() / (Game.rows + 1)));
```

**This will be the result:**

[image]

http://postimg.org/image/794mrqpnn/

Note the missing view at position 0.

In my other run, after I removed the line code:

```
b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth() / (Game.cols), parent.getHeight() / (Game.rows + 1)));
```

**the picture was shown but the height got shrank.**

[image]

http://postimg.org/image/nmomaw5sz/

When I added the line code:

```
b.setHeight(Game.gv.getMeasuredHeight() / Game.rows);
```

**the result became half the way between result 1 and result 2:**

[image]

postimg.org/image/ubv5qwr4z/

I just want to get the picture at position 0 with the same dimensions of the others.

### Edited:

**XML of the grid view I'm using:**

```
<GridView
    android:id="@+id/gvGame"
    android:layout_width="fill_parent"
    android:layout_height="375dp"
    android:gravity="center"
    android:horizontalSpacing="3dp"
    android:padding="3dp"
    android:stretchMode="columnWidth"
    android:verticalSpacing="1dp" />
```

**And this the code regarding the grid view in the Game class:**

```
gv = (GridView) findViewById(R.id.gvGame);
gv.setNumColumns(cols);
gv.setAdapter(new GameAdapter(getApplicationContext()));
```

Comment: Have you put a logging (print) statement in your code to MAKE CERTAIN that the 0 case is being treated in all cases?  Also, what does your GridView setup code look like?  You might also try using a more simple `LayoutParams.FILL_PARENT` so that you don't necessarily have to define size yourself, You should be defining the width and height of a row and column upon creation of the GridView, so a fill parent param `SHOULD` work in this case.

Comment: [trumpetlicks](http://stackoverflow.com/users/1408212/trumpetlicks) .. actually i don't have a constant width and height for the views as i cut the picture according to an scanned number of the columns and rows. so the width of each depends on the width of the grid view / number of columns and same goes for the height which depends on the grid view height / number of rows.

Answer (score 0):

Im pretty sure you want your code to look as follows, whether this truly answers your question or not.

```
public View getView(int position, View convertView, ViewGroup parent) {
    Button b;
    if (convertView == null) {
        b = new Button(mContext);
        b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth() / (Game.cols), parent.getHeight() / (Game.rows + 1)));
        //b.setHeight(Game.gv.getMeasuredHeight() / Game.rows);

        // This code from below SHOULDNT need to be done if the view already exists
        // Im also assuming that the drawable WILL NOT change, if it does, the 2
        // lines below may move outside this if statement
        Drawable d = new BitmapDrawable(Game.splittedBitmaps[position]);
        b.setBackground(d);


        b.setId(position);
        b.setTag("Image_" + position);
        b.setOnClickListener(Game.s);
        Game.buttons[position] = b;
    } else {
        b = (Button) convertView;
    }

    return b;
}
```

Comment: Yeah I think you're right, this was a small mistake. I fixed it but still the problem is the same. Again, I like to remind you that number of columns and rows are dynamically changing (not constant), otherwise, I would have defined them with the GridView in the xml file. I edited the question (added the grid view code in xml and the way I instantiated it in the Game class). Thanks

Comment: @user3396919 - I don't mean defining them statically in xml file. I mean define them dynamically in code, but define them using the standar GridView API, then allow the button to size ITSELF WITHIN the gridview confines.

Answer (score 0):

Pretty old post but if anyone get the same issue, here is the possible reason and solution:

You are probably setting the adapter and its list in the creation cycle of the fragment/activity (onCreate, onStart, etc..), therefore when the first view creation is done inside your adapter the GridView is not drawn yet and has a width of 0.

It does not happen to the other created views probably because the creation of the first one forced the GridView to be drawn.

You can find a bunch of solutions on that post: https://stackoverflow.com/a/24035591/3495069

I've personnaly ended up with the post method:

```
    mGridView.post(new Runnable() {
        @Override
        public void run() {
            mGridView.setAdapter(mAdapter);
        }
    });
```

Answer (score 0):

I had this same problems too. Here's what it'd looks like if it's your code.

```
if (convertView == null) {
    b = new Button(mContext);
    b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth() / (Game.cols), parent.getHeight() / (Game.rows + 1)));
    //b.setHeight(Game.gv.getMeasuredHeight() / Game.rows);
} else {
    b = (Button) convertView;
    if (b.getHeight() == 0)
        b.setLayoutParams(new GridView.LayoutParams(parent.getWidth() / (Game.cols), parent.getHeight() / (Game.rows + 1)));
}
```